# One script working but another is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-framework, jquery-events

I am planning to use two different JavaScript files, one for desktop screens and another for iPhone screens.

The reason I am using it is because I need to reduce the size of the cube.
Everything is working fine in the desktop browser.
However, when I reduce the browser size, the cube is not showing up.

Here are the two different JS files:

I don't see any errors in the console related to these scripts.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RH4HD/) of the issue.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() { location.reload();

     Gallery.setOptions({
            size: 78,
            lightbox: false,
            //animation:  'drop'
            //speed:      500,
            //closeOnEsc: true,
            //slideshow:  false,
            //slideshow_speed: 3000,
            //cube_speed: 1000
        });

 })

$(window).bind('resize', function() { location.reload();

     iphGallery.setOptions({
            size: 78,
            lightbox: false,
            //animation:  'drop'
            //speed:      500,
            //closeOnEsc: true,
            //slideshow:  false,
            //slideshow_speed: 3000,
            //cube_speed: 1000
        });

 }

)
```

Comment: Try without the last comma after "false", some Javascript interpreters are picky about that.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Both scripts reload the current page, so the following instructions shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: @Dr.Molle: thanks for your reply....when i reduce the browser window the cubes are not showing up

Comment: @Perleone: i updated the fiddle but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/RH4HD/1/